# Singlet and Triplet Pairing Mixing in Unconventional Superconductors

Tags: superconductivity

I am currently reading https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.63.239 and I am wondering if its possible in a single band superconductor to have coexisting singlet and triplet pairing?

Based on the Hamiltonian

$$
H =  \sum_{k,s} \epsilon_k a_{k,s}^\dagger a_{k,s} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k,k', s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4} V_{s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4}(k,k') a_{-k, s_1}^\dagger a_{k, s_2}^\dagger a_{k', s_3} a_{-k', s_4}
$$

and a Mean-field decoupling of the form

$$
\Delta_{s, s'}(k) = - \sum_{k', s_3, s_4} V_{s', s, s_3, s_4} \langle a_{k', s_3} a_{-k', s_4} \rangle 
$$

$$
\Delta_{s, s'}^*(k) = - \sum_{k', s_1, s_2} V_{s_1, s_2, s', s} \langle a_{-k', s_1}^\dagger a_{k', s_2} \rangle 
$$

$$
H = \sum_{k,s} \epsilon_k a_{k,s}^\dagger a_{k,s} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k,s_1,s_2} \Delta_{s_1,s_2} (k) a_{k, s_1}^\dagger a_{-k, s_2}^\dagger - \Delta_{s_1,s_2}^* (-k) a_{-k, s_1} a_{k, s_2}
$$

they arrive at the following block diagonal form for the billinear Hamilton Matrix

$$
\mathcal{E}(k) = \begin{pmatrix} \epsilon{k} \sigma_0 & \hat{\Delta}(k) \\\\
-\hat{\Delta}^*(-k) & - \epsilon{k} \sigma_0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Where $\sigma_0$ is a $2x2$ identity matrix and $\hat{\Delta}(k)$ is given by its matrix elements above.

Due to the fermionic commutation relations we know:

$$
\hat{\Delta}(k) = - \hat{\Delta}^T(-k)
$$

The authors write that there are two types of solutions:

1. Singlet pairing
   $$
   \hat{\Delta}(k) = i \sigma_y \psi(k)
   $$
2. Triplet pairing
   $$
   \hat{\Delta}(k) = i (\mathbf{d}(k) \cdot {\boldsymbol \sigma} ) \sigma_y
   $$

The authors describe now that each solution has of course different symmetry properties, concerning for example spin rotational invariance under $SU(2)$ or time-reverseal invariance. E.g. triplet pairing break time-reversal invariance.

**Now my question:** Is it clear that one can only have one type of solution in a single band superconductor? Depending on $V$ wouldn't it also be energetically favorable to have a mix of singlet and triplet pairing and thereby for example $d+p$ wave pairing? Or is there a reason why it should only be one or the other? Especially when I am only breaking a discrete symmetry instead of a continuous one.